# PHP-Yii2 how to set dynamic values in params

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to set dynamic value in params.php.

**For example:**
`'MainUrl' => Yii::$app->request->hostInfo.'web/images'`.

How to set dynamic  values in params.php and  params-local.php?

Comment: Whats the problem .. you get an error ?.. unaspected result?

Comment: Though it is not disallowed you shouldn't set params dynamically. They are rather regarded as constants. ([guide about this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#params))

Comment: As my knowledge we can't get value cause in entry script (frontend/web/index.php) file declared config file before application  running so...